# Send Mail from Android in HTML format

Tags: android

I had shown the HTML file content in WebView.That is available in SDCard, I need to send that HTML Content as a email in the same format(HTML). 
Note: I don't want to send it from email client application.I need to send it without user interaction

Answer (score 1):

At this [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/942224) there is a nice explanation of using javaMail API.  and other option is you can use **[mailchamp](https://www.mailchimp.com)** library.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, It is possible**

1st off, give the manifest permission to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

then follow the tutorial

but little bit tricky, check this tutorial 
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
String htmalContentFromSdcard = "";

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/html");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "abc@gmail.com");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Demosubject");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmalContentFromSdcard));
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            finish();
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ting(getString(R.string.share_email_no_client));
        }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I had mention that, without using email client i need to send mail.By using intent it will send mail using email client only. I need to send mail without user interaction "Biraj Zalavadia"

Comment: Not possible because of security aspect.You need some server in between to achieve this without user interaction.